# Where can I find Camera Raw for offline installation for Mac?

Tags: photoshop, adobe-camera-raw

I friend of mine is going to update Camera Raw on the computers at his company and he asked me for help. The problem is that the office shares a very low speed Internet connection and it would block the Internet connection too long if all computers were to get the update from the server individually.

I tried to find an offline installation DNG for Camera Raw 8.3, but could only find the related DNG Converter 8.3. Does anyone know where to get the file?

Comment: Have you tried to contact Adobe?

Comment: Yes I did a few days ago per email, but they haven't replied yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is  this Adobe blog post with link for ACR for Photoshop CC or CS6:

http://blogs.adobe.com/crawlspace/2011/03/keeping-photoshop-up-to-date.html#notconnected

Comment: Great! That sure was a hidden one.